# How configure xtensa-lx106-elf to compile c++ code for esp8266 using nonos-sdk?

Tags: c++11, cmake, sdk, esp8266, xtensa

I'm having difficulties to compile c++ code with xtensa-lx106-elf.

The manufacture of the chip I'm using (esp8266) provides a sdk (nonos-sdk). 
One of the libraries in this sdk implements functions to allocate memory in the chip: *os_malloc*, *os_realloc*, etc.

When compiling **c** code, everything works fine. When compiling **c++**, object files are generated successfully but I get a lot of error messages from the linker, complaining about undefined references to *abort*, *free*, *malloc* and a very odd one to *__gxx_personality_v0*.

My make file was created using cmake. Bellow the options that I use with the compiler.

```
target_include_directories( 
  ${elf_file}

  PUBLIC
  src/
  inc/
  /opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/driver_lib/include/
  /opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/include/
  )

target_compile_options(
  ${elf_file}

  PUBLIC
  -mlongcalls -c -std=c++11 -v
  )

target_link_libraries( 
  ${elf_file}

  PUBLIC

  -L/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib
  -L/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/ld
  -Teagle.app.v6.ld

  -nostdlib

  -Wl,--start-group
    -lmain -lhal -lnet80211 -lcrypto -lupgrade -lwpa -llwip -lpp -lphy -v
  -Wl,--end-group

  -ldriver
  -lcirom
  -lgcc
  )
```

Compiler errors:

```
CMakeFiles/MasterSPI-esp8266.elf.dir/src/main.cpp.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
CMakeFiles/MasterSPI-esp8266.elf.dir/src/spi.cpp.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2.o):(.literal+0x8): undefined reference to `abort'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2.o): In function `execute_cfa_program':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2.c:1212: undefined reference to `abort'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2.o): In function `read_encoded_value_with_base':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-pe.h:252: undefined reference to `abort'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2.o): In function `execute_stack_op':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2.c:905: undefined reference to `abort'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2.o): In function `uw_update_context_1':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2.c:1420: undefined reference to `abort'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2.o):/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2.c:1560: more undefined references to `abort' follow
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.literal+0x20): undefined reference to `malloc'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o):(.literal+0x24): undefined reference to `free'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o): In function `size_of_encoded_value':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-pe.h:88: undefined reference to `abort'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o): In function `read_encoded_value_with_base':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-pe.h:257: undefined reference to `abort'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o): In function `base_from_object':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:256: undefined reference to `abort'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o): In function `start_fde_sort':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:409: undefined reference to `malloc'
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:412: undefined reference to `malloc'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o): In function `end_fde_sort':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:575: undefined reference to `abort'
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:590: undefined reference to `free'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o): In function `__register_frame':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:118: undefined reference to `malloc'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o): In function `__register_frame_table':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:156: undefined reference to `malloc'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o): In function `__deregister_frame_info_bases':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:200: undefined reference to `free'
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:216: undefined reference to `abort'
/opt/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libgcc.a(unwind-dw2-fde.o): In function `__deregister_frame':
/home/wjg/Repo/esp-open-sdk-20170622/crosstool-NG/.build/src/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:231: undefined reference to `free'
```

Something that catch my attention is that it seems the linker is trying to find many files in the path: "*/home/wjg/Repo/*" and I can confirm it doesn't exist in my computer. Can't understand this behavior.

---

Tools info:

**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04LTS

**Compiler**: xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-60-g37b07f6) 4.8.5

**CMake**: cmake version 3.12.0-rc3

**nonos-sdk**: 2.2.1

Comment: Have you considered just using PlatformIO? It has great ESP8266 support using nonos-sdk (which the Arduino SDK is built on), and you won't need to muck around directly with the Xtensa toolchain. https://platformio.org/

Comment: `it seems the linker is trying to find many files in the path: "/home/wjg/Repo/"` - No, the linker isn't trying to find these files. The linker just points to the usage of the unresolved symbols in `libgcc` library, which has been compiled from these source files (on another machine). After compiling, these files are no longer needed. No worries about that.

Comment: @JohnRomkey Thanks for this recommendation, I tested and my c++ code works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to link against the C++ libraries? These are the libraries I use during linking my C++ files on the ESP8266:

```
-lhal -lphy -lpp -lnet80211 -llwip2 -lwpa -lcrypto -lmain -lwps \
-laxtls -lespnow -lsmartconfig -lairkiss -lwpa2 -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc
```

Especially the -lstdc++ is important! Try to add those libraries to your makefile!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably importing stdlib or trying to use malloc, free, and some other stdlib functions, which are not available in this SDK.

Rename all places that use malloc() with os_zalloc() and try again.

This usually happens when the sources point to, or import, standard libraries. Your compiler flags tell you why: -nostdlib